# Adding two vector shapefiles together (one on top of the other) in QGIS

Tags: qgis, shapefile, layers, merge, inkscape

I understand how to merge two vector shapefiles together but I don't know how to layer one layer on top of another one and export it to make it permanent?

I would like to add the GreaterMan shapefile on top of the GreatBritain shapefile to highlight the location of GreaterManchester (as shown in the attached picture).

I know this is a quick fix but I can't work out how to do this.

[image]

I have merged the two shapefiles together using the union tool so that only the Greater Manchester in the attribute table is displayed and I have run a simple select features using an expression "DISCRIPTIO" LIKE 'Metropolitan District' to highlight all of the Greater Manchester districts.

The purpose is to export the shapefile, so I can import the shapefile in Inkscape.

Comment: What do you want to export it to, for what purpose? I think knowing this will help us understand how best to answer.

Comment: I would like to combine the two shapefiles (Great Britain.shp and GreatMan.shp) to export it as a new shapefile but maintain the order, so that GreaterMan.shp as the in front of the GreatBritain.shp and maintain the colourscheme

Comment: Colors are not depending of the order in a shapefile. You should learn the GIS phylosophy of data management and map design with QGIS.  Please have look to the user manual.

Comment: Why do you need to combine the two shapefiles? What purpose? As @HugoRoussaffa-GeoDatup says you can control the order and the colour with the set up you already have in your screenshot. Do you need to print it? Share a single file with someone else? At the moment it is not clear what you are trying to do that I different from what you already have done, so in some sense the question doesn't make sense. You can't combine the shapefiles and have one on top of the other, they will be the same shapefile. You can change the colours of your polygons based on attributes.

Comment: The purpose is to export the shapefile, so I can import the shapefile in Inkscape. I have merged the two shapefiles together using the union tool so that only the Greater Manchester in the attribute table is displayed and I have run a simple select features using an expression "DISCRIPTIO" LIKE 'Metropolitan District' to highlight all of the Greater Manchester districts. @HugoRoussaffa-GeoDatup did post a good explanation on how to but it seems he has deleted it.... Could you please upload it again because I never got chance to attempt it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To just keep it simple you could just use your GreatBritain Shapefile, select the polygons of Greater Manchester and give them a unique attribute. Then use this attribute to style them whatever colour you want. I don't think you need involve a separate shapefile.

There are a number of ways of doing this, one way, that preserves the original data into the shapefile is to create a new attribute column.

Select the polygons of Greater Manchester using the `Select Features` tool. (If you hold down `ctrl` when selecting you can click on each polygon one at a time to add to your selection)

[image]

Then open the attribute table, toggle into editing mode and open the field calculator.

[image]

Create a new field, call it whatever you want, I have called it 'group', and enter a value, I have used 'GreaterMan'

[image]

Save the changes, come out of edit mode. Then open the layer properties and go to the style tab. Choose `Categorized`, and select the new attribute column that you have just set up. Click classify and change the colours to whatever you want.

[image]

It will give you the shapefile set up as in your question

[image]

That's one method, there several other routes you could use to get the same, or similar result.

Answer (score 0):

Export a map to inkscape is usually done  by export map as svg with the same named plugin . Be aware to Use old symbology cause the plugin doesn't recognised the symbology v2.

Comment: You are welcome. please check the answer as solution.